# Manipulation of generic objects

Tags: java, arrays, generics

I have an abstract super class `Show` that has a Date filed `openDate`.It has several sub classes and at the end I have created a generic `TheaterSchedule` class that can take the super class and all the sub classes as parameter.Then in that generic class I did the following to add objects of the subclasses:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
SimpleDateFormat dateText = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
TheaterSchedule<Show> mixed = new TheaterSchedule<Show>();
try {
  mixed.addShow(new Musical("Hamilton", "Lin-Manuel Miranda", "Lin-Manuel Miranda", "Richard Rodgers Theatre", dateText.parse("08/6/15")));
  mixed.addShow(new MusicalComedy("Wicked", "Winnie Holzman", "Stephen Schwartz", "Gershwin Theatre", dateText.parse("10/30/03")));
  mixed.addShow(new Drama("The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Nighttime","Simon Stephens","Ethel Barrymore Theatre", dateText.parse("10/5/14")));
  mixed.addShow(new Musical("The Lion King", "Roger Allers and Irene Mecchi", "Elton John and Tim Rice", "Minskoff Theatre", dateText.parse("11/13/97")));
  mixed.addShow(new Comedy("An Act of God", "David Javerbaum", "Booth Theatre", dateText.parse("06/6/2016")));
  mixed.addShow(new Musical("Kinky Boots", "Harvey Fierstein", "Cyndi Lauper", "Al Hirschfeld Theatre", dateText.parse("04/4/13")));
  TheaterSchedule.addMusicalComedy(mixed, "The Book of Mormon", "Trey Parker, Robert Lopez and Matt Stone", "Trey Parker, Robert Lopez and Matt Stone", "Eugene O'Neill Theatre", dateText.parse("03/24/11"));
} catch(java.text.ParseException ex) {
  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
System.out.println("Selected Broadway Shows:");
TheaterSchedule.printSchedule(mixed);
```

Now I want to crate a method that can take a specific date and return an array of the objects(sub classes of the `Show` class) that have been there before and up until that Date.I expect the following output:

```
Broadway shows open since 04/01/14:
Wicked - Playwright: Winnie Holzman, Composer: Stephen Schwartz at
Gershwin Theatre since 10/30/03
The Lion King - Playwright: Roger Allers and Irene Mecchi, Composer:
Elton John and Tim Rice at Minskoff Theatre since 11/13/97
Kinky Boots - Playwright: Harvey Fierstein, Composer: Cyndi Lauper at
Al Hirschfeld Theatre since 04/04/13
The Book of Mormon - Playwright: Trey Parker, Robert Lopez and Matt
Stone, Composer: Trey Parker, Robert Lopez and Matt Stone at Eugene
O'Neill Theatre since 03/24/11
```

In order to get the output I have to do the follwoing:

```
 try {
  Date when = dateText.parse("04/01/14");
  Show[] current = TheaterSchedule.<Show>getShowsOpenSince(mixed, when);
  System.out.println();
  System.out.println("Broadway shows open since " + dateText.format(when) + ":");
  for (int i=0; i<current.length; i++)
    System.out.println(current[i]);
} catch(java.text.ParseException ex) {
  System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
```

I need to build the `getShowsOpenSince` method that will return array of the shows before and up until the given time. I created the method header as the following:

```
public static <E> E [] getShowsOpenSince(TheaterSchedule<E> object,Date date) {
```

Now inside the method I have to do certain manipulation that will check the dates of the objects in the ArrayList, and return an array(not ArrayList!) of the objects that match the dates.My `Show()`  super type constructor has a Date parameter called `openDate` .I want to do like `compareTo` maybe with objects in `mixed.addShow(...)` list.But the problem is that I also have different other parameters in  there and I really don't know how to specifically compare the parsed date text(see my code blocks) with the date object that I will put in the method.

Comment: Why'd you make it generic?

Comment: So that it can parameterize the class and I can define class types.I'm specifically learning the use of generic here.

Comment: Can't you just traverse the `TheaterSchedule` object and compare the dates to the `date` object passed?

Comment: And does a call to `addShow` add the show to an `ArrayList`?

Comment: date is a Date object and TheaterSchedule object is another type, although it has a date object in it's parameter.So then how can you compare two different types of objects?

Comment: Yes addShow adds shows in the ArrayList

Comment: Do you have a `getDate` method in your `Show` class? That way you could get the date for that show and compare it to the parameter

Comment: Yes I have a getDate method.

Comment: Well if you compare the Show's date to the parameter and it results in true you can add that Show to an array or ArrayList

Comment: Why did you declare a type variable on the `getShowsOpenSince` method? Actually, from your examples, I don't think generics are useful for what you're doing at all. `TheaterSchedule<Show>` is exactly the same as if you had made the class non-generic and had `addShow(Show show)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic type variables is totally useless for the programmer, since it's an `E` of unspecified type you can't make any assumptions on it: you can just pass `E` instances around to other generic objects.

Whatever you need to do with `TheaterSchedule<E>`, you must apply a bound to the `E` type so that you will have something to work on.

This is better explained in official documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/bounded.html), but the point of this is that you are allowed to declare that a type variable is somehow bounded to a type, for example

```
public <E extends Show> E[] getsShowOpenSince(TheatherScheduler<E>, Date date) { ... }
```

so that, whatever is `E`, you can be sure that's at least a `Show` instance and be able to invoke everything that's defined for `Show`. This also implies the opposide of the metal: you won't be allowed to pass to `getsShowOpenSince` a `TheatherScheduler<String>` since `String` doesn't extend `Show`.

Comment: I'm wondering you have a E[] return type but at the same time you defined the method as void?

Comment: @user65: just a typo.